# Problem updating to KDE 4.9.1

Tags: fedora, kde

I wrote this on the terminal:

```
sudo yum -y update 
[sudo] password for brallan: 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package akonadi.i686 0:1.7.2-1.fc17 will be obsoleted
--> Processing Dependency: libakonadiprotocolinternals.so.1 for package: kdepimlibs-akonadi-4.9.1-3.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libakonadiprotocolinternals.so.1 for package: 7:kdepim-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libakonadiprotocolinternals.so.1 for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-libs-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libakonadiprotocolinternals.so.1 for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libakonadiprotocolinternals.so.1 for package: 7:kdepim-libs-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
---> Package akonadi-mysql.i686 0:1.8.0-1.fc17 will be obsoleting
---> Package ark.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ark.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ark-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ark-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package audiocd-kio.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: audiocd-kio-libs(x86-32) = 4.9.1-1.fc17 for package: audiocd-kio-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libaudiocdplugins.so.4 for package: audiocd-kio-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkcddb.so.4 for package: audiocd-kio-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkcompactdisc.so.4 for package: audiocd-kio-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
---> Package calligra.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                             
---> Package calligra-braindump.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                     
---> Package calligra-braindump.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                   
---> Package calligra-braindump-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                
---> Package calligra-braindump-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                              
---> Package calligra-core.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                          
---> Package calligra-core.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                        
---> Package calligra-flow.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                          
---> Package calligra-flow.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                        
---> Package calligra-flow-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                     
---> Package calligra-flow-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                   
---> Package calligra-karbon.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                        
---> Package calligra-karbon.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                      
---> Package calligra-karbon-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                   
---> Package calligra-karbon-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                 
---> Package calligra-kdchart.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                       
---> Package calligra-kdchart.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                     
---> Package calligra-kexi.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                          
---> Package calligra-kexi.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                                        
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-mysql.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                             
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-mysql.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                           
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-postgresql.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                        
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-postgresql.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                      
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-sybase.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                            
---> Package calligra-kexi-driver-sybase.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update                                                                                          
---> Package calligra-kexi-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated                                                                                                     
---> Package calligra-kexi-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-kexi-map-form-widget.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-kexi-map-form-widget.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-krita.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-krita.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-krita-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-krita-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-okular-odpgenerator.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-okular-odpgenerator.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-plan.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-plan.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-plan-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-plan-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-reports-map-element.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-reports-map-element.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-sheets.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-sheets.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-sheets-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-sheets-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-stage.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-stage.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-stage-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-stage-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-words.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-words.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package calligra-words-libs.i686 0:2.5.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package calligra-words-libs.i686 0:2.5.2-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package dragon.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be obsoleting
---> Package gwenview.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package gwenview.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package gwenview-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package gwenview-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package jovie.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package jovie.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package jovie-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package jovie-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kactivities.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kactivities.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kamera.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kamera.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kamoso.i686 0:2.0.2-3.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kamoso.i686 0:2.0.2-5.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kate.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kate.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kate-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kate-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kate-part.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kate-part.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kcalc.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kcalc.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kcharselect.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kcharselect.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kcm_colors.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kcm_colors.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kcolorchooser.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kcolorchooser.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-baseapps.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-baseapps.i686 0:4.9.1-2.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-baseapps-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-baseapps-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-2.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-printer-applet.noarch 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-printer-applet.noarch 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-runtime.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-runtime.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: nepomuk-core >= 4.9.1 for package: kde-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnepomukcore.so.4 for package: kde-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
---> Package kde-runtime-flags.noarch 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-runtime-flags.noarch 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-runtime-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-runtime-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-workspace.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-workspace.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kde-workspace-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kde-workspace-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdeartwork-kxs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdeartwork-kxs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdeartwork-screensavers.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdeartwork-screensavers.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdegraphics-thumbnailers.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdegraphics-thumbnailers.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdelibs.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdelibs.i686 6:4.9.1-4.fc17 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0) for package: 6:kdelibs-4.9.1-4.fc17.i686
---> Package kdelibs-common.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdelibs-common.i686 6:4.9.1-4.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdemultimedia-common.noarch 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdemultimedia-common.noarch 6:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdemultimedia-dragonplayer.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be obsoleted
---> Package kdemultimedia-kio_audiocd.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be obsoleted
---> Package kdemultimedia-kmix.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be obsoleted
---> Package kdemultimedia-libs.i686 6:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdemultimedia-libs.noarch 6:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-common.noarch 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-common.noarch 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-kdnssd.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-kdnssd.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-kget.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-kget.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-kget-libs.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-kget-libs.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-krdc.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-krdc.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-krdc-libs.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-krdc-libs.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-krfb.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-krfb.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdenetwork-krfb-libs.i686 7:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdenetwork-krfb-libs.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdepim.i686 7:4.8.5-4.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepim.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdepim-libs.i686 7:4.8.5-4.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepim-libs.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdepim-runtime.i686 1:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepim-runtime.i686 1:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libkgapi.so.0 for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxerces-c-3.1.so for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkolab.so.0 for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkolabxml.so.0 for package: 1:kdepim-runtime-4.9.1-1.fc17.i686
---> Package kdepim-runtime-libs.i686 1:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepim-runtime-libs.i686 1:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdepimlibs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepimlibs.i686 0:4.9.1-3.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdepimlibs-akonadi.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdepimlibs-akonadi.i686 0:4.9.1-3.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdeplasma-addons.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdeplasma-addons.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdeplasma-addons-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdeplasma-addons-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdesdk-common.noarch 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdesdk-common.noarch 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdesdk-okteta.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdesdk-okteta.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdesdk-okteta-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdesdk-okteta-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdesdk-umbrello.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdesdk-umbrello.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdevelop.i686 9:4.3.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdevelop.i686 9:4.3.1-2.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdevelop-libs.i686 9:4.3.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdevelop-libs.i686 9:4.3.1-2.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kdm.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kdm.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kgpg.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kgpg.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kgreeter-plugins.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kgreeter-plugins.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kio_msits.i686 7:4.8.5-3.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kio_msits.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kmix.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be obsoleting
---> Package kolourpaint.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kolourpaint.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kolourpaint-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kolourpaint-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package konsole.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package konsole.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package konsole-part.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package konsole-part.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kross-interpreters.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kross-interpreters.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kross-python.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kross-python.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kruler.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kruler.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ksnapshot.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ksnapshot.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ksysguard.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ksysguard.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ksysguard-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ksysguard-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ksysguardd.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ksysguardd.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ktorrent.i686 0:4.2.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ktorrent.i686 0:4.3.0-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package ktorrent-libs.i686 0:4.2.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package ktorrent-libs.i686 0:4.3.0-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kwallet.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kwallet.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kwebkitpart.i686 0:1.2-0.3.20111030.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kwebkitpart.i686 0:1.3-0.1.20120726git.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kwin-gles-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kwin-gles-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package kwrite.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package kwrite.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package libkdcraw.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package libkdcraw.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package libkexiv2.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package libkexiv2.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package libkipi.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package libkipi.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package libktorrent.i686 0:1.2.1-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package libktorrent.i686 0:1.3.0-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package libkworkspace.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package libkworkspace.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package marble.i686 1:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package marble.i686 1:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package marble-libs.i686 1:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package marble-libs.i686 1:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package okular.i686 0:4.8.5-3.fc17 will be updated
---> Package okular.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package okular-libs.i686 0:4.8.5-3.fc17 will be updated
---> Package okular-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package okular-part.i686 0:4.8.5-3.fc17 will be updated
---> Package okular-part.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package plasma-scriptengine-python.i686 0:4.8.5-2.fc17 will be updated
---> Package plasma-scriptengine-python.i686 0:4.9.1-6.fc17 will be an update
---> Package pykde4.i686 0:4.8.5-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package pykde4.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package system-config-printer-kde.i686 7:4.8.4-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package system-config-printer-kde.i686 7:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package akonadi.i686 0:1.7.2-1.fc17 will be updated
---> Package akonadi.i686 0:1.8.0-1.fc17 will be an update
---> Package audiocd-kio-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package kdelibs.i686 6:4.9.1-4.fc17 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0) for package: 6:kdelibs-4.9.1-4.fc17.i686
---> Package libkcddb.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package libkcompactdisc.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package libkgapi.i686 0:0.4.2-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package libkolab.i686 0:0.3.1-3.fc17 will be installed
---> Package libkolabxml.i686 0:0.8.1-2.fc17 will be installed
---> Package nepomuk-core.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package nepomuk-core-libs.i686 0:4.9.1-1.fc17 will be installed
---> Package xerces-c.i686 0:3.1.1-2.fc17 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 6:kdelibs-4.9.1-4.fc17.i686 (kde)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I solve this? I have the 'required package' in /usr/lib/
I use Fedora 17, KDE 4.8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either hit the mirror while it was still updating, or your local yum cache is out of sync. Either way, the solution is the same:

```
yum clean all
```

then try again.

---

It's possible you also have a wrong version of `xz-libs`, the package being complained about. Check to make sure you didn't get a version of it from a third party repository.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, it might be the mirror isn't completely up to date, or perhaps the updates were pushed out partially. You can try `yum clean metadata` (that blows away `yum`'s idea of available packages, etc, but *not* what it has already downloaded), and try again, adding `--skip-broken` (that omits packages that can't be updated for whatever reason). Maybe you need a few rounds of doing this. Look at the package it is complaining about, try `yum reinstall` that. Consider running `package-cleanup` (from the `yum-utils` package), it helps in fixing a lot of inconsistencies.